# Sorcerer with Scribe Scroll feat

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, feats

We're wondering if a Sorcerer that has the feat [Scribe scroll](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#scribeScroll) is capable to write a scroll from a mage book without consuming the spell from it.

Answer (score 8):

## No, that's not how scrolls work

You don't copy scrolls from spellbooks.  You create scrolls from spells you cast into them as part of the crafting process.  Any character with the Scribe Scroll feat who can cast at least one spell can create scrolls of any spell they can cast provided enough time and experience (and resources, which they can get with enough additional time if they are lacking).

Separately, wizards (which I presume you mean by 'mage') can copy spells *from* scrolls or other wizards' spellbooks into their spellbook(s).  This is a wizard-only thing that sorcerers (even if they take scribe scroll) can't do.  Copying from a scroll *does* destroy the scroll, and copying from a book doesn't.  This may be what you are thinking of, but neither class can use spellbooks like scrolls nor can either class bypass the need to cast a spell for crafting by having it in a spellbook they own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use a magic item such as a wand in this process instead of spell slots; a per-day wand would seem wisest. Depending on the definition of "...you cast...".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't intending to contradict, merely expand upon.